High max-age in strict-transport-security is seen as 1
Today, I ran a few SSL tests on my website and both tests indicate my HSTS security setting is too low of 1 second, and that I should set it for at least one year, however I tried to set mine to a bunch of same digits that would cover at least 10 years as follows:
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=77777777

When examining the number with a calculator, it takes less than 32 bits.
So why are tools reporting that as if the max-age is only set to 1?
And I picked the same digits because its easier for compression if/when HTTP headers are/can be compressed for people later on.

That max-age corresponds to just under 2.5 years. What tools are reporting that the max-age is set to 1?

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest
